# Show that C[0,1] is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

The set $C[0,1]$ is the set of all continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$. Show that $C[0,1]$ is a vector space. Note: for $f,g$ (as elements of) $C[0,1]$, we define $(f+g)(x) = f(x)+g(x)$ and for a scalar $c,$ $(cf)(x) = cf(x)$.

The first step in showing that something is a vector space is to show that vector $u$ + vector $v$ is in $V$.

I don't know what I'm supposed to assign as $u$ and $v$, though. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to show the following:

1. The $0$ function is in $C[0,1]$.
2. If $f,g \in C[0,1]$, then $f + g \in C[0,1]$. The only property you know about $f$ and $g$ is that they are of $C[0,1]$, and you can't assume anything else.
3. Similarly, if $c$ is a scalar and $f \in C[0,1]$, then $cf \in C[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

You would let $u$ be a function in $C[0,1]$ and $v$ be a function in $C[0,1]$.  Then $u+v$ is also in $C[0,1]$ because the sum of two continuous functions is also continuous.

I think the problem is supposed to illustrate that any set of elements can be a vector space, not just a set of $n$ dimensional vectors.  In this case, the set of elements is composed of functions.

But, to verify that the set is a vector space, you need to prove all the properties of a vector space apply.  For example, if $u$ and $v$ are $2$ dimensional vectors, their sum must be a $2$ dimensional vector.  In this case $u$ and $v$ are continuous functions, so their sum must be a continuous function.