# The set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ is a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, self-learning

I'm a beginner in the course of Linear Algebra; please bear with me if the question seems too trivial.

The set of all continuous functions on interval $[0,1]$ is a vector space.

I have trouble in understanding this. 
What does a continuous function on $[0,1]$ mean? That the range lies within $[0,1]$?

For it to be a vector space, it needs to satisfy vector additivity.

Say, we take a vector with continuous function $f(t)=0.9$ which belongs to $V$.  Another vector belonging to $V$ has continuous function $g(t)=0.8$.

For vector additivity, we add the elements of vector (in this case I'm considering only 1 element in the vector). Here the new vector would give us $0.8+0.9$ which us not in $[0,1]$.  And yet this is a valid vector space.

I'm sure I'm missing something. I'm probably not able to understand what the question demands.

Comment: Is it functions from $[0,1]$ or to $[0,1]$? If it is to $[0,1]$, this is not a vector space.

Comment: Presumably we are talking about continuous *real* functions on $[0,1]$.  A continuous real function on $[0,1]$ is a function $f$ with domain $[0,1]$ and codomain $\Bbb R$ satisfying the definition of what it means to be [continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function).

Comment: @RushabhMehta The question states "all continuous functions"

Comment: @JMoravitz So is it the domain we are referring to when we say "on [0,1]"?

Comment: It almost certainly is referring to the set of functions $\{ f: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}: f \text{ is continuous on [0,1]} \}$

Comment: In my experience, yes that is usually the case.  See [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1732877/show-that-c0-1-is-a-vector-space?rq=1) for further information on how to proceed.

Comment: I would definitely think so. I would even say I am sure provided this is in the basic linear algebra course.

Comment: @michalOut Yes. Makes sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks!

Comment: @TheoC. Makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Depending on the course, you might either be allowed to assume that the sum of two continuous functions is again continuous, or you might be required to prove that directly from definitions, something that is often done in a real analysis course rather than a introductory linear algebra course.  If it is not clear to you how much you need to prove, I would err on the side of caution and try to prove it yourself for completeness and for the extra practice if nothing else.

Comment: $[0,1]$ is the domain of functions, the codomain is the whole line. You can check by definition that the sum of two continuous functions in $[0,1]$ is still a continuous function in $[0,1]$ and the same for scalar multiplication, so the space of continuous functions is closed for sum and multiplication by scalar. The other axioms of vector space are of immediate verification.

Comment: @RicardoFreire Got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuous function on $[0,1]$ is a function

$$f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$$

which is continuous for every point in $[0,1]$. Since the sum and scalar multiples of continuous functions are also continuous (and addition is commutative) we have a vector space since there are additive inverses $(f-f=0)$ and a distinguished 0 element.

What might be throwing you is the fact that there is no finite basis for this vector space.

Comment: Don't we need also the following eight [axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) for the qualification as a vector space?